# Capturar parámetro de un enlace dinámico de un botón

Tags: javascript

Tengo un botón que agrega productos a un carro de compras; la cantidad es tomada de un input (donde el usuario elige por ejemplo agregar 4 productos) y es cargada bajo el parámetro &qty en la siguiente url:

https://www.mercadorepuestos.co/checkout/cart/add?sku=7541&qty=2&seller=1&sc=1&price=5822100&cv=e85402363851bd03c728f86233cc76b6_geral:6252472121BE483C67533699C5A7E356&sc=1

Lo que necesito hacer es capturar mediante un script el valor de ese parámetro &qty.

Gracias.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Puedes obtener un parámetro de un atributo href así:

```js
$('.buy-button').bind('click',function(){
          event.preventDefault();//en tu caso me parece que no necesitas esta línea porque ya está bloqueado el comportamiento por defecto del link
          var url = ($(this).attr('href'));
          var qty = getURLParameter(url, 'qty');
          alert(qty);
       });


 

      function getURLParameter(url, name) {
         return (RegExp(name + '=' + '(.+?)(&|$)').exec(url)||[,null])[1];
       }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="buy-button qd-sbb-on" href="https://www.mercadorepuestos.co/checkout/cart/add?sku=7541&amp;qty=4&amp;seller=1&amp;sc=1&amp;price=5822100&amp;cv=e85402363851bd03c728f86233cc76b6_geral:6252472121BE483C67533699C5A7E356&amp;sc=1">Comprar<span class="qd-bb-productAdded"><i class="icon-thumbs-up"></i> <span>Produto adicionado</span></span></a>
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la respuesta Pedro, lo que pasa en este caso es que la URL no cambia, la cantidad es tomada desde un input (donde el usuario elige por ejemplo agregar 4 productos) y esos productos son agregados al carrito cuando se hace clic en el botón "comprar"; EJ:  /checkout/cart/add?sku=66892&amp;qty=1

Comment: No entiendo porqué dices que la URL no cambia y por otro lado das ejemplos con URLs, hay una inconsistencia en tu explicación en ese aspecto, de todas formas, que tal si lees el valor del input al momento de clickear el botón "comprar"?

Comment: Gracias de nuevo por la respuesta, envío URLs porque son las que están en el href: EJ: href="https://www.mercadorepuestos.co/checkout/cart/add?sku=7541&qty=1&seller=1&sc=1&price=5822100&cv=e85402363851bd03c728f86233cc76b6_geral:6252472121BE483C67533699C5A7E356&sc=1"

Lo que pasa es que parámetro qty se toma de forma dinámica.

He tratado igualmente capturar el valor del input pero no ha sido posible.

Es posible que trates de agregar un producto, ej: https://www.mercadorepuestos.co/emblema_trasero_referencia_d09w51730/p para que me entiendas mejor?

Saludos!

Comment: Lo que necesitas en tal caso es leer un parámetro desde el atributo href del link, que va cambiando, he editado mi respuesta para mostrarte como lograr esto, espero que te sirva.

Comment: Crack! muchas gracias Pedro!